# How can I embed a Github Gist inside of a React component?

Tags: reactjs, gist

I'm trying to use the Github Gist API to get all of my gists and embed them on a web page. Each Gist holds a blog post that I contain within the following component:

```
function BlogEntry(gist)  {
    return (
        <div>
            {gist.createdAt} {gist.id} {gist.description}
            <script src={"https://gist.github.com/seisvelas/" + gist.id + ".js"}></script>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The first line of the render'd `div`, `{gist.createdAt} {gist.id} {gist.description}` works, so I know I'm successfully interacting with the API. However, the second part with the `script` tag does nothing.

I tried this on a plain HTML document and he pattern `<script src="https://gist.github.com/seisvelas/gist_id.js"></script>` (which I got from the Gist website itself) does work given a valid gist_id.

I'd guess this has to do with how `script` tags behave in React components. It hadn't even occurred to me that this would be an issue. Could anyone recommend a simple workaround so I can get these Gists embedded successfully?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you embedding a <script> tag here? What do you expect this to do? Are you trying to run your gist in this page? Or do you want to just show the code itself?

Comment: You need to use `iframe` instead of `script`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I want to show the contents of the Gist

Comment: @Clarity That doesn't work, which makes sense. The Gist embed link is a bunch of JS code. Importing it as an iframe won't do the same thing (I tried it, it just renders a blank iframe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this problem, I resolved it using the npm package [react-embed-gist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-embed-gist). It's dead simple and looks like this:

```
import ReactEmbedGist from 'react-embed-gist';

// Only required attribute is gist
<ReactEmbedGist gist="msaracevic/5d757e2fc72482a9a4a439969500c2eb"
                wrapperClass="gist__bash"
                loadingClass="loading__screen"
                titleClass="gist__title"
                file=".bash_profile.sh"/>
```

Highly recommend!

Comment: Glad to be of help. In case you are wondering how to do it without the module, I've commented the source code here: 
https://github.com/msaracevic/react-embed-gist/blob/master/src/ReactEmbedGist.js

Comment: @MiroslavSaracevic Thanks for making something awesome! I wouldn't have been able to do my project the way I wanted without react-embed-gist!

Comment: Hi, it's not clear how to add the ReactEmbedGist method to a Markdown (or MDX) file that contains the actual text after which I need the Gist to be embedded. Do you know how to do that? (There's no way to 'import' in an MDX file.) Thanks.

Comment: According to the MDX readme, you can indeed import in an MDX file: https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx#example

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to display it in dark mode ?

Answer (score 6):

use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-gist) npm package, worked for me.

**Step 1:** Install the package

```
npm i react-gist
```

**Step 2:** import in your react component

```
import Gist from "react-gist";
```

**Step 3:** put your gist id

```
 <div>
     <Gist id="f824ffb7bafec535d0b6452179f2d790" />
 </div>
```

OR

```
 <div>
     <Gist id='f824ffb7bafec535d0b6452179f2d790' file='java-file' />
 </div>
```

if you have multiple files in the same gist

---

```
<Gist id={string} file={string} />
```

Where,

- id {string} Id of the gist file
- {string} Name of a specific file in a multi-file gist

Comment: FWIW, I easily got this library working in Gatsby, but had problems with `react-embed-gist`. One note: the `id` attribute may need to include your GitHub account name, e.g. `:name:/f824ffb7bafec535d0b6452179f2d790`.

Answer (score 2):

This solution lets you embed anything in an iFrame:

```
import Frame from 'react-frame-component';

<Frame  initialContent="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body><script src='https://gist.github.com/[YourUsername]/aa7101515bb1586857ca43beac8e0abc.js'></script></body></html>" />
```

Just replace the gist url in the code above with your own.

Frame component available at:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-frame-component

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, a `<script>` tag embeds JavaScript code into the page to execute. It won't display the code from the URL specified in the `src` attribute.

The `gist` object from the Gist API contains all the data you need. Don't try to build the URL yourself. Instead, look at what else is in that `gist` object. For example, [according to the documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#get-a-single-gist), `gist.files` is an object that contains information about each file in the gist. The keys in this object are the file names and those contain a `content` property gives the content of the file So if you have a file named `hello.js`, you can do `gist.files['hello.js'].content`. Since you probably don't know the file in advance, you can just loop over the keys of the `gist.files` object.

In general, when you are consuming an API, you should look carefully at the documentation to see what information it gives you.

Comment: Nope, this is just plain wrong. Put this on a plain HTML document: `<script src="https://gist.github.com/seisvelas/0dded61a10f716793645fe152885b5a5.js"></script>`. 'display my code' is EXACTLY what it does.

Comment: Yes, it executes JS code, but that JS code uses a bunch of document.writes to create an embedded display of a Gist. Just try it yourself and you'll see what I mean instantly. This question has nothing to do with Gist's API.

Comment: @seisvelas Ok, I see what you mean. I thought that the link was directly to your code. It's not, though. Instead, it is some JavaScript that executes like you said.